# Separate comma of a string but not included within brackets and parenthesis

Tags: javascript, object

I have a elements that has a attribute name of data-options , every element has different configurations , it is not a json formatted for readability and easy maintenance.

```
<table scoa-table data-options="
responsive:true,
setHeaders:['header1','header2','header3'],
colWidth : 300,
data : {
   "data1" : "value1",
   "data2" : "value2",
   "data3" : "value4",
}`
"></table>
```

I need to parse a string into a comma separated values

So far, I've got the following :

```
var foo = jQuery("[scoa-table]").attr("data-options"),
    result = foo.split(/,(?![^\[]*\])/gm)
```

but it works only in brackets not within on parenthesis

This is what I expected

```
(3) ["responsive:true", 
    "setHeaders:['header1','header2','header3']",
    "colWidth : 300",
    'data : {"data1" : "value1","data2" : "value2","data3" : "value4",}'
   ]
```

Comment: Have you come across `Object.keys()`?  This gives you the top level key names for a given object.

Comment: If the structure is arbitrary, I think the easiest solution would be to turn it into an object first, if at all possible. If the input is trustworthy, use `eval`. This looks like an X/Y problem, IMO

Answer (score 1):

instead of using the comma, try the "\n" for new line as split argument:
for ur input u can use:

```
> result = foo.split(/\n(?![^\{]*\})/gm)
[ 'responsive:true,',
'setHeaders:[\'header1\',\'header2\',\'header3\'],',
'colWidth : 300,',
'data : {\n   "data1" : "value1",\n   "data2" : "value2",\n   "data3" : "value4",\n}' ]
```

BTW: u might need to replace `\n` too and the last comma in the splitted line like:

```
> result = foo.split(/\n(?![^\{]*\})/gm).map(function (e) {return  e.replace(/\n|,$/g, "")})
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the object and use `JSON.stringify` to convert the key and value to a string before pushing it in an array

```js
var foo = {
  responsive: true,
  setHeaders: ['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
  colWidth: 300,
  data: {
    "data1": "value1",
    "data2": "value2",
    "data3": "value4",
  }
}

let arr = [];
for (let keys in foo) {
  arr.push(`${keys}:${JSON.stringify(foo[keys])}`)
}
console.log(arr)
```